# How to get first n values from perl Hash of arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

Experts,
  I have a hash of array in perl which I want to print the first 2 values.

```
my %dramatis_personae = (
    humans => [ 'hamnet', 'shakespeare', 'robyn', ],
    faeries => [ 'oberon', 'titania', 'puck', ],
    other => [ 'morpheus, lord of dreams' ],
);

foreach my $group (keys %dramatis_personae) {
    foreach (@{$dramatis_personae{$group}}[0..1]) { print "\t$_\n";}
}
```

The output I get is 
"hamnet
shakespeare
oberon
titania
morpheus
lord of dreams" 
which is basically first two array values for each key. But I am looking to have the output as:

hamnet
shakespeare

Please advise how I can get this result. Thanks!

Comment: A hash does not have an ordered set of values, you need to structure this in another way.  You could use http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/values.html to get all the values, then slice the first two elements from it, but the result is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Keys of hashes are not ordered, so you should specify keys ordering by yourself. Then you can concatenate arrays from each key specified and take first two values from resulting array, is it what you want ?

```
print "\t$_\n" foreach (map {(@{$dramatis_personae{$_}})} qw/humans faeries other/)[0..1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hashes are unordered, so what you requested to achieve is impossible. Unless you have some knowledge about the keys and the order they should be in, the closest you can get is something that can produce any of the following:

- `'hamnet', 'shakespeare'`
- `'oberon', 'titania'`
- `'morpheus, lord of dreams', 'hamnet'`
- `'morpheus, lord of dreams', 'oberon'`

The following is an implementation that does just that:

```
my $to_fetch = 2;
my @fetched = ( map @$_, values %dramatis_personae )[0..$to_fetch-1];
```

The following is a more efficient version for larger structures. It also handles insufficient data better:

```
my $to_fetch = 2;
my @fetched;
for my $group (values(%dramatis_personae)) {
   if (@$group > $to_fetch) {
      push @fetched, @$group[0..$to_fetch-1];
      $to_fetch = 0;
      last;
   } else {
      push @fetched, @$group;
      $to_fetch -= @$group;
   }
}

die("Insufficient data\n") if $to_fetch;
```